# Access database suddenly slows way, way down

Tags: ms-access, networking

A client has an Access database with the client MDB on the local computer and the data tables in a linked MDB on the server. There are several client computers hitting the data MDB on the server. Performance has always been pretty good.

But yesterday the performance took a nose dive on all clients. It now takes a few minutes to open the front-end and a few minutes more to open any tables. If I open the data MDB from across the network it also takes a few minutes to open a table. If I copy the data MDB locally it opens just fine.

I tried relinking the tables. No joy. I tried compacting/repairing. No joy. Rebooted everything. No joy.

I suspect a network issue, but spreadsheets and word docs open fine across the network. Copying large files across the network works fine.

I am stumped. Any other ideas on might be happening or additional debugging steps I can take?

Thanks, Brad

Comment: Were any software packages recently installed on the server, or anything that could be siphoning the speed/memory?

Comment: Assume you compacted both the FE & BE databases? You could look at task manager on the server. Have seen where *The Tech Guru* decided to virus scan everything during the day; or a faulty network. I would keep other users out and focus on one workstation. The obvious questions: did anybody make an app change (doubtful since opening BE is slow)?; were there some massive data inserts? Have also seen the primary keys of tables vanish in the night.

Comment: Sort of off-topic but not at all; you should properly deploy an Access MDB to each user.  Never, EVER put a shared front end on a server.  It's a recipe for disaster.  Splitting FE/BE is good, now go the next step and deploy the FE to each user.  It will eliminate 80% of your problems 100% of the time.  Even MS suggests it!  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-an-Access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US